# Unity Photon Error Close Connection problem(Help)

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I was making a game and I wanted to put a Kick System in the game, but I encountered such an error, can anyone help?

> CloseConnection is disabled. No need to call it.
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is to set Photo nNetwork.EnableCloseConnection to true...You have to call it when the game starts or elsewhere but it can't be synced across clients because it is not associated with the server.